# Testcafe role problems with logout

Tags: authentication, testing, automated-tests, testcafe, user-roles

I use the Testcafe roles in my script to avoid new logins each test inside a fixture. It works really good, but I run into a problem where I cannot find any solution.

If I use the role to log in into the page and I use the common page functions to logout of the page, it means to click the selector Logout, then the upcoming script still thinks that the role is still logged in and the test fails. 
As sample:

```
test('Login und Logout', async t => {
        const loginheader = Selector('.login-header')
        await t
        .useRole(bc3Tester)
        .navigateTo(inputStore.metaUrl)
        .click(Selector('.cl-sidemenu-button'))
        .click(Selector('.side-menu-logout.cl-asset-button-animation'))
    await t
           .wait(2000)
           .expect(loginheader.exists).ok()
});
```

If I run this test a second time it will fail at

```
.click(Selector('.cl-sidemenu-button'))
```

because the role script not work (No auto login again)

```
const bc3Tester = Role(inputStore.metaUrl, async t => {
await t
   .typeText(Selector('#email'), inputStore.clLogin, {
      caretPos: 0
   })
   .typeText(Selector('#password'), inputStore.clPassword, {
       caretPos: 0
   })
   .click(Selector('span').withText('Login'))
});
```

Because it will not log in. Any idea?

Comment: This behavior looks like an issue. We will need to debug it on a real site. If you can provide us with your site and credentials, please open an [issue](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?template=bug-report.md) on GitHub and provide as much details as possible. Thank you in advance.

Comment: ok, will try to get a test account from our admin

Comment: Hello. I cannot create a issue with the data to reproduce the test case. To reproduce or debug this issue I have to provide data for a test channel in our system, and I cannot publish this to the public. So please give me a way where I can submit this confidential data to a team member.

Comment: It looks like the best solution in this situation is to send us this information via email. You may reach out to us at `support@devexpress.com`.